# select date+time+timezone with oracle db

Tags: database, oracle, date

I would like to get a date with the following format:

> 2009-01-15T09:13:51.0Z

I use the following statement:

```
SELECT to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-mm-DD HH24:MI:SS.')
```

But that returns:

> 2012-11-07 16:12:00.

How can I ad the `T` in the middle and `0Z` at the end?

Is this possible or do I have to use concatenation?

Comment: That format is ISO8601, which you can read about here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put it in double quotes.

```
to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-mm-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS."0Z"')
```

Answer (score 0):

to_char((sysdate,''YYYY-mm-DD HH24:MI:SS TZD')  returns the abbreviated timezone on the users computer.  If another timzone is you will need to add/subtract hours from your own timezone to get time correct in current timezone.  There is an oracle format with timezone data.
rather than making column a date you can make it one of the following sql types

```
Type TIMESTAMP adds miliseconds but no timezone.
Type TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE same as timestamp but with timezone it was saved with.
Type TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIMEZONE same as timestamp but all is saved in local timezone.
```